# Can I use table schemas as bounded context?

Tags: sql, domain-driven-design

When programming , I use bounded contexts to separate domains. Does it makes sense to use table schemas to do that ?

Comment: Does it make sense to you and your environment to do that?

Comment: I was just wondering  if there's a use for such approach

Comment: I've used table schemas when creating a data warehouse and also working with MIS it makes sense to have separation - but it's a matter of choice really.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the sql server sample database, Adventureworks uses schemas.
https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/02/use-the-adventureworks-sample-database-for-your-examples/

Answer (score 1):

A bounded context should own its own data.

If you have two bounded contexts you should also have two data 'domains' to serve each context respectively.

You can either deploy each domain-of-data to its own database, or, as your question alludes to, if your needs do not demand separate database for each domain then using a schema to 'isolate' the tables in a single database is an approach that I take.